# Convert HH:MM:SS to Minutes in Netezza

Tags: netezza

I am trying to figure out how to convert a field that has storage National Character Varying HH:MM:SS to minutes for one field, and seconds for an additional field.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you saying you want to represent 1:03:00 as 63 minutes or simply trying to extract the 3 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select cast(sub.timestring as time) as timeval
,extract(hours from  cast(sub.timestring as time)) as hours
,extract(minutes from  cast(sub.timestring as time)) as minutes
,extract(seconds from  cast(sub.timestring as time)) as seconds
,extract(epoch from  cast(sub.timestring as time)) as totalTimeValueInSeconds
from (select '02:31:12' as timestring) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Niederee's columns into what you requested, but this directly gives you the columns.

```
select 
  '21:51:40'::nvarchar(8) hhmmss
  ,extract(epoch from hhmmss::time) seconds
  ,seconds / 60.0 minutes;
```

The output:

```
  HHMMSS  | SECONDS |   MINUTES
----------+---------+-------------
 21:51:40 |   78700 | 1311.666667
```